# MDX IIF evaluation of string value

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

another MDX question;

as stated in this question 
[MDX If statement syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232109/mdx-if-statement-syntax)

i have a value of type string that holds a 4 digit number. i would like to evaluate the first number or character of that string

so what i do is this:

```
IIF(([Kostensoort].[Kosten code] >= 7000 AND [Kostensoort].[Kosten code] < 8000), 
[Measures].[Inkoop bedrag] + [Measures].[Bank bedrag], 
[Measures].[Inkoop bedrag])
```

what i suspect to happen, according to the documentation is the following;

syntax: IIF(Evalutation, true expression, false expression)

what actually happens is that the evaluation returns false in what ever way i try to write the expression. i know this, because the value gets printed. if i enter a static number, that also gets printed in my cube.

yes, i do know that im intepreting the value of Kosten code as a integer even though its a string, i tried using Instr and Left too, which yielded no results either.

i'm kind off at a loss here on what to do. Any insights are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are grabbing the currentmember of your dimension.  Your example is likely returning "All"

```
[Kostensoort].[Kosten code].currentMember
```

Once you change that you can use [StrToValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144951.aspx).

```
IIF((StrToValue([Kostensoort].[Kosten code].currentMember) >= 7000 AND [Kostensoort].[Kosten code] < 8000), 
[Measures].[Inkoop bedrag] + [Measures].[Bank bedrag], 
[Measures].[Inkoop bedrag])
```

Comment: this seems logical to me, however when i run this the IIF statement will never get true. i also noticed that the field im quering has a double value, so i tried 7000.0 instead, which did'nt work either. i used this:
 IIF(
STRTOVALUE( [Kostensoort].[Kosten code].CURRENTMEMBER ) >= 7000.0 ,//expression
1,// true
0 // false

Comment: i marked your question as the answer because it helped  me to get to it: if is use (StrToValue([Kostensoort].[Kosten code].currentMember.Name) i get the value that i need. why i need to use Name instead of Value i do not know, but the IIF statement now returns what i expect it to return! so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the string into a numerical value; try something like that:

```
CLng( [Kostensoort].[Kosten code] ) >= 7000
```

Comment: this doen't work either, as stated in the other answer. i tried to use it, even though it showed up in the mdx reference guide on msdn. what i noticed too, is that if i tried to get `[Kostensoort].[Kosten code].currentMember` as ouput, it returned an empty cell, like the current member has no value. but when i mouse over, i see that the current member has a value